# Find formula for nth term of series (confused how to do it).

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

So my question is find a formula for the sum of the first $n$ terms of the series (not sequence):

$$\frac{4}{81}+\frac{4}{729}+\frac{4}{6561}+\frac{4}{59049}+\ldots~\textrm{upto }n\textrm{ terms}$$

How would I do this? I know the formula for writing the sum of a geometric series, but I don't know what to put for r. I know an is 4. Would r be 1/9 or 1/81?

Comment: The compact (closed) form of the sum is: $\displaystyle 4\cdot \sum_{i=2}^n \left(\dfrac{1}{9}\right)^i$

Comment: Use index shifting of sum and the formula for sum of a finite GP to get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here, $r$ should be the ratio between successive elements in the sequence.  This is computed in your case as 1/9, and you can write arbitrary terms as $4/81 * (1/9)^n$ in general.  The finite version of the formula for geometric sums should then provide your answer.

Comment: oh ya thank you! i realized i forgot the 4/81 fraction! thanks!

Comment: it said that sum formula is not correct. i also did 4/81∗(1/9)1-n but that wasnt correct either. I do not see how this is incorrect.

Comment: You have to be careful about indices when using the sum formula, note that my formulation has n=0 as the first term, as opposed to n=1

Answer (score 2):

First, I think that last one must be $\;5\color{red}9049\;$ , second: think of powers of $\;9\;$ beginning with $\;9^2\;$ in the denominators.